# Explain the utility of the jQuery object (“$”)

Tags: jquery

```
$.trim() 
$.each() 
$.inArray() 
$.extend() 
$.proxy()
$.browser
$.contains()
$.data()
```

Utility function in jQuery the same as utility jQuery object ("$")? please explain the utility of the jQuery object (“$”)?

Comment: What do you mean by "utility"? Do you have any **specific** question about this?

Comment: kindly explain the utility of the jQuery object (“$”)?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Anything you don't understand? If you don't need jQuery, why not remove it from your application? If you are using it already, shouldn't that explain what jQuery does?

Comment: When someone asks you to clarify, don't just repeat the *exact same wording*.  That's not clarifying.

Comment: Are you asking what each function does?  Or why there exists `$.function()`?  Or what `$` means?

Comment: thank you everyone for your feedback! my question has been resolved, regarding the utility of jQuery object ("$")! which from what i understand now is the same thing as writing (jQuery in your html but using the symbol  "$")

Comment: For future reference: your terminology should be "**the use of**" not "the utility of"

Answer (score 1):

It is a normal JavaScript Object. Has some functions and properties.

Comment: thank you for your feedback! my question has been resolved, regarding the utility of jQuery object ("$")! which from what i understand now is the same thing as writing (jQuery in your html but using the symbol "$")